# (line != null) not working in Java BufferedReader

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader

I'm programming a java program that reads from file and I need it to stop at the end of the file, I remember using "While(line != null)" in the past, to take every line in the text, however, it's not working for me right now. My method is this:

```
int contator = 0;
String line2 = "";
while (line2 != null) {
            line2 = reader2.readLine();
            fi[contator]=line2;
            for(int i =0;i<ret.length;i++){
                System.out.println("line2 : "+line2+"ret : "+ret[i]);
                if(line2.toLowerCase().contains(ret[i])){
                    fi[contator] = line2;
                    etiqueta[contator]=etiqueta[contator]+" reti";
                }   
            }contator ++;
         }
```

It's working, I see the prints right, but when it has to end, prints the last line with null, and exits with the "java.lang.NullPointerException"; printing

```
line2 : Number of words ret : 361.
line2 : Something here ret : 369.
line2 : other things ret : 379.23
line2 : nullret : 250.5//this is the problem, after this it throws exception
```

**I tried other methods like:**

```
while (line2 != "null" )
while (line2.length()>0)
while (!line2.isEmpty)
```

Nothing worked, I'm on Eclipse IDE Mars.2; any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `while (line2 != "null" )` Please rethink this approach and think about what this really does. Especially think about the meaning of `"null"`.

Comment: Yeah, I know it doesn't have any sense, I'm doing some sort of "casting" to string here, I was a litle lost, to many hours programming maybe.

Comment: No, you're not casting anything here, since `line2` is already a String, but you're checking if the variable `line2` refers to the same String object as the String literal `"null"`. And `"null"` is very different than `null`. But you already know why your original `while (line2 != null)` didn't work as well, so that's all good :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should change the order of calling `line2 = reader2.readLine();`

```
line2 = reader2.readLine();
while (line2 != null) {
    // Your code
    line2 = reader2.readLine();
}
```

---

Let's take a practical example using your own code : `line2` contains the last line of the stream.

```
while (line2 != null) {              // line2 is not null right now but contains the value of the last line
    line2 = reader2.readLine();      // Since the last line has been read already, this returns null
    // Your code is used with null and thus throws the exception
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`while` loops check at the beginning of the loop. By putting `line2 = reader2.readLine();` after the check, you've introduced the possibility that `line2` will *now* be `null` because `reader2.readLine()` returned `null`:

```
while (line2 != null) {         // <=== Not null here
    line2 = reader2.readLine(); // <=== But now it is, because
                                //      readLine returned null
    // ...
}
```

The usual idiom, if you want to use a `while` loop for this, is:

```
while ((line2 = reader2.readLine()) != null) {
    // ...use line2
}
```

That assigns to `line2` and then checks the resulting assigned value against `null`. (That also makes the `line2 = "";` above the loop unnecessary.)

It's one of the **very few** places doing an assignment and check in an expression is commonly seen, as it's so idiomatic.

The longer form is:

```
line2 = reader2.readLine()
while (line2 != null) {
    // ...use line2

    // get the next one
    line2 = reader2.readLine();
}
```

...but by duplicating the line, it introduces the possibility that you'll modify one of those but not the other, introducing a bug.

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing line2 against null.

You are assigning a new value to line2.

You are doing something with line2.

Hmm, what could be the problem here?

Comment: "Hmm, what could be the problem here?" Yes, that's what OP is asking. (While this points in the right direction, it is not really an answer, more like a comment)

Comment: I am sure that there will be plenty of people directly throwing the full solution at him. So, what does it matter if one person invites him to step back and gives him the chance to figure himself what is going on ... sometimes you just need somebody telling you that you can look at your problem from a different perspective.

Comment: This answer just bothers me, sometimes programming you can have a lapsus and don't see whats happening, and if you program in a lot of languages, this happen commonly, if you are not going to answer, just save it please, or maybe you could comment, but I don't see a reason here

Comment: @Amnor This wasn't meant to be rude. I simply reworded your code to human language. You know, taking away the abstractions that prevent you from getting to the (very simple) core of this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I've seen that the problem is quite simple, i just didn't saw it. @Yassin Hajaj answer is working

Answer (score 3):

The body of the while loop will still run even when line2 is null. (You're essentially using the previous value of line2 as the termination condition, which is of course incorrect.) So a NPE will be thrown.

Why don't you put the assignment inside the while condition?

```
while ((line2 = reader2.readLine()) != null)
```

Assigning inside a loop test is not to everyone's taste (some folk find it obfuscating) but it is useful sometimes, this case being one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned "" to line2, then comparing it with `null`.
Possible solution could be

```
while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(thisLine);
}
```